# Controller vs Request specs in Rails. How to do them properly?

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

So there's an argument that I'm reading about that says Controller tests should be unit tests of the controllers and Request specs should be more of an integration test that involves the router, the controller, and the response. That's the philosophy in the codebase that I'm working in. Given that, what's the best way to write both tests given that I have this controller:

```
class Api::WineController < ApplicationController

  def show
    wine = Wine.find(params[:id])

    render json: { id: wine.id, varietal: wine.varietal }, status: :ok
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render json: { error: { message: "Wine not found") } }, status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

So my request spec is the one that looks like a typical, integration-y controller test that most people write:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Wine API", type: :request do

  describe '#get /api/wine' do
    let!(:wine) { create(:wine) }
    subject { get "/api/wine_invite_beta/wine_tokens/:id", params }

    let(:params) {
      {
        id: wine.id
      }
    }

    context "and the wine exists" do
      it "returns back a JSON response of names" do
        subject

        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq("id" => wine.id, "varietal" => wine.varietal)
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
      end
    end

    context "and wine does not exist" do
      it "returns back a JSON response of errors" do
        subject

        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq("error" => { "message"    
       ....
       end
    end
  end
end
```

So the request spec uses the http methods (:get is the one used), to hit the router which then hits the controller. This seems more like an integration test.

The controller test should do without the router and just test the class and its methods like I would test the model. Is that right? Do people agree? This is how I'm writing it:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::WinesController, type: :controller do
  describe "#show" do
    let(:controller_instance) { described_class.new }
    subject { controller_instance.show }

    before do
      allow(controller_instance).to receive(:params) { params }
    end

    let(:params) { { id: 1} }

    context "and wine token exists for user" do
      let!(:wine) { create(:wine) }

      it "calls render with the wine token data" do
        expect(controller_instance).to receive(:render).with(
          json: {
            id: wine.id,
            varietal: wine.varietal
          },
          status: :ok
        )

        subject
      end
    end
```

Is that okay? I'm merely setting an expectation that a method is called within the controller because that seems like a command. That feels wrong though. The `render` method seems more like a query than a command and so perhaps I should be inspecting the state of the controller after render is called. Does anyone know how to do this?

More generally, what do people think of this approach to making controller vs request specs?

Comment: Me, I don't bother with controller specs. 95% of my controller actions are two liners: "call some object and render response". That object is tested separately. And there's nothing left to test in the controller itself.

Comment: interesting, I often hear it too. Which book suggests that?